# Sql DB Project executing different post-deployment scripts

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, database-project

I want to execute different post-deployment scripts on Virutal machines than the one on production servers, so that I can fill the vm's with some static user data that I don't want to be on production.
My first thought was setting it to a different build configuration and determining by that which script to execute, but my colleges want (insist) that the build config on the vm's and prod should stay the same.

I'd appreciate any advise/suggestions

Comment: There are several different approaches already addressed on stack overflow, such as including files with build scripts or using sqlcmd variables.  If you're having problems with a specific method then please post a question about that.

Comment: @DanielGimenez I couldnt seem to find any can you give me a link?